# Использование метода onFormSubmit() при обработке ответов из нескольких форм

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet, google-forms

Я новичок, до этого работал только с VBA. Не сочтите вопрос глупым или не стоящим внимания. У меня разработаны несколько гугл форм ответы на которые отображаются на соответствующих листах в гугл таблицах. Я создал триггер на функцию 
function onFormSubmit(e)
...
мои инструкции
... 
}
для обработки события заполнения формы.
Впоследствии осуществляется выполнении дальнейших инструкций при заполнении ответов на любую из разработанных форм. Как правильно выполнить разграничение выполнения кода в зависимости от заполнения ответов по конкретной форме (по ID формы я так понимаю) ? Другими словами мне необходимо выполнить реакцию для каждой формы по отдельности. Пробовал создать несколько функций и для каждой из них написать триггер - однако это не принесло желаемого результата. Подскажите в каком направлении двигаться или может у кого есть ссылка на подробный разбор.

Answer (score 0):

Очень странно, что вы попали в такую ситуацию, т.к. этого просто не может быть, или вы что-то не так делаете с самого начала.

Задание триггеров для конкретной Формы

```
/**
 *
 */
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('onFormSubmit')
    .forForm('ABC123')
    .onFormSubmit()
    .create();
}
```

Чтение идентификатора Формы при срабатывании события отправки Формы

```
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.FormsOnFormSubmit} e
 */
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  console.log(e.source.getId());
}
```

*Обновлено*

Возможно, вы создавали триггер из интерфейса контейнера, привязанного к Таблице. Тогда вы создали это для Таблицы, и адресное задание триггера невозможно. Воспользуйтесь вторым примером для переключения заданий между соответствующими Формами. Не навязываю, но роутинг может быть очень простым:

```
/**
 *
 * @param {GoogleAppsScript.Events.SheetsOnFormSubmit} e
 */
function sheetsOnFormSubmit(e) {
  const sheet = e.range.getSheet();
  const sheetName = sheet.getName();
  if (/первый этап/i.test(sheetName)) return respondentActionFirstAction();
  if (/второй этап/i.test(sheetName)) return respondentActionSecondAction();
  return respondentActionMissedAction();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.

Comment: @KiaPride, является лучшим ответом?

Comment: Вы верно отметили, я создавал триггер из интерфейса контейнера, привязанного к Таблице - поэтому первая инструкция не дала должного результата. Поэтому я пойду по второму пути который обозначен в обновлении Вашего ответа. Как показало время, мне придется использовать большое количество форм привязанных к одной таблице. Спасибо!

Comment: @KiaPride, так что насчет лучшего ответа?